# How to define a stationary point of the MINLP problem?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization, discrete-optimization

As we all know, [KKT point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions) and [stationary point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_point) are well definied when the optimization variables are continuous in the problem.

Now, I want to know whether there exists some special points except for globally optimal solution in discrete optimization problems. For example,
$$\begin{aligned}\min_{x,y}\quad& f_0(x,y), \\
\mathrm{s.t.}\quad&f_k(x,y)\leq 0,\forall k\\
&x\in\mathcal X,\\
& y\in\mathbb Z.\end{aligned}$$
where $\mathcal X$ is a compact and convex set. Now how to define the stationary point of this problem?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: This is not fully discrete, it's mixed real-integer. What do you know about the $f$'s?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, thanks a lot for your help. Yes, this is an MINLP problem. Suppose $f$'s are differentiable with respect to $x$ for any given $y$. Except for the globally optimal solution, what else do some special points exist? And how to define these points? Thanks.

Comment: The experts are at Operations Research SE: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minlp I would consider posting there with a notification at the very top of each question linking to the same question on the other Stack Exchange site.